# Neo4j 2.0 with Play 2.2.1

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, playframework-2.2

I'm looking for a way to user Neo4j 2.0 in a Play 2.2.1 application.

Everything I find is only working with either an older version of Neo4j or Play 2.2.1. Like this: https://github.com/sgougi/play21-frames-neo4j-plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the current version off the plugin 1.2.1 supports play 2.2.1 and neo4j 1.9.5 using spring data.

Currently i am lifting the neo4j version to  2.0 Beta as Johannes already mentioned.

If you have any questions how this plugin works you can ask me and Johannes.

Answer (score 0):

tuxBurner is developing a play-neo4jplugin and shares his code on github at https://github.com/tuxBurner/play-neo4jplugin . This plugin is really cool and i am enjoying it a lot in a lot of projects.

Currently this version runs on play 2.1.2 and neo4j 1.9.5, but he will release the next days the lift to play 2.2 and neo4j 2.0.0-RC1.

Just wait for a few more days and enjoy :)

Cheers,
Johannes